# Change the CSS image Position on required form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the CSS image error position on required form input

The `gray` and `blue` are set using CSS and setfocus but what I need is a javascirpt or jquery to set CSS image to red on error. Having a hard time figuring the error handling process out.

[image: My BG Image]

Comment: can you provide some code please ?

Comment: If you can create plunker with your code would be best.

Comment: We need an example pls. So far, I would suggest to add a class on error to your input field and define css in there.

Answer (score 1):

OK got it working with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

#docs {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
  </style>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
});//]]> 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to suggest anything.

But actually you can modify the image(background-image) using CSS itself.

Have a look at this example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="msg_box">
  <span class="msg_icon"></span>
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="msg_box success">
  <span class="msg_icon"></span>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.msg_icon{
  background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/mail_email_envelope_send_message-32.png');
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.success .msg_icon{
  background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/circle-icons-1/64/mail-32.png');
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/647h7yxk/)

Here the background image of the icon is changed when the parent container is having the `success` as class name! Here, we used the CSS selectors to modify the image. No need of jquery/javascript. But in your case, we won't be able to suggest anything until we see the code!